# Spring mongodb exception HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

I am using mongoDB and spring mvc and tomcat7 i get exception as soon as I add this code.

I have checked on google but i cant find anything. The application works fine without the monogDB stuff but when i run the monogDB test its fine.

The monogDB is on a different server and the tomcat is on a different server

**The error**

```
type Exception report

message Filter execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from      fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoOptions.<init>(Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions;)V
    com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:138)
    com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:126)
    com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:115)
    org.krams.commerce.login.UserDAO.internalDatabase(UserDAO.java:65)
    org.krams.commerce.login.UserDAO.searchDatabase(UserDAO.java:24)
    org.krams.commerce.login.CustomAuthenticationManager.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationManager.java:42)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.krams.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>commerce</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>commerce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>



  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
          <version>2.11.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.6</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>integration-test</goal>
                          <goal>verify</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>

    <finalName>commerce</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Thanks you in advanace**

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you might have a mismatch between the MongoDB driver version you're developing against and the one on the webserver.  MongoClient only came in version 2.11, so my suspicion is that the version of the driver you have in Tomcat is older.

Answer (score 0):

I use Java EE (JSF + EJB).  The Mongo client is in a @startup @singleton ejb, and when @PostConstruct void init() calls new MongoClient(), I got the same problem.

In fact I was able to do things by running the EJB as a standalone program (adding a main method that calls init()).

I tried to clean and restart, and problem gone.  Technically this is not an answer and Nabeel might have fixed it, but I hope this can help other people.